# AngularJS Material md-list hight completely different in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-material

I'm fairly new to using AngularJS and I'm working with Angular Materials, and I've come across an issue that I cannot understand.

When writing a md-list, it renders fine in Firefox, and IE (11), but in chrome, each md-list-item takes the full height of the window, but only when I'm running the code for my site.

If I view other pages (eg. the Angular Material demos), or put the code into a shareable editor, like codepen, or jsfiddle, they render fine.

The code below is is a test template which displays incorrectly

```
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc2/angular-material.min.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="BlankApp" ng-cloak>
  <div style="height:400px;width:500px;">
      <md-list>
        <md-list-item ng-click="null">Item 1</md-list-item>
      </md-list>
      <md-list>
        <md-list-item ng-click="null">Item 2</md-list-item>
      </md-list>
      <md-list>
        <md-list-item ng-click="null">Item 3</md-list-item>
      </md-list>
  </div>


  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc2/angular-material.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module('BlankApp', ['ngMaterial']);
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

CodePen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pyqKZr

Live Demo of the failed layout: http://angular.deathwishgame.co.uk/

Why does this only happen when rendering my own page alone, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running into https://github.com/angular/material/issues/8094
The only workaround is to give the list items a height/max-height.

There seems to be a pull-request pending review.

Comment: Fantastic! Adding height controls to `md-list-item` and the subclasses controlling height worked a treat. Thank you very much. I'm looking forward to the next RC. Unforunately, I make use of the md-colors directive, so I can't fall back on rc1.

Answer (score 1):

Use angular-material version 1.0.9 instead of 1.1.0. Then, it will work fine.

**Try running this code , I have corrected your code which you have hosted**

```
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Angular Material style sheet -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.9/angular-material.min.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="BlankApp" ng-cloak>
  <!--
    Your HTML content here
  -->
  <div style="height:400px;width:500px;">
      <md-list>
        <md-list-item ng-click="null">Item 1</md-list-item>
        <md-list-item ng-click="null">Item 2</md-list-item>
        <md-list-item ng-click="null">Item 3</md-list-item>
      </md-list>
  </div>


  <!-- Angular Material requires Angular.js Libraries -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Angular Material Library -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.9/angular-material.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Your application bootstrap  -->
  <script type="text/javascript">    
    /**
     * You must include the dependency on 'ngMaterial' 
     */
    angular.module('BlankApp', ['ngMaterial']);
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put all the `md-list-item` in just one `md-list`.

```
<div style="height:400px;width:500px;">
      <md-list>
        <md-list-item ng-click="null">Item 1</md-list-item>
        <md-list-item ng-click="null">Item 2</md-list-item>
        <md-list-item ng-click="null">Item 3</md-list-item>
      </md-list>
</div>
```

Comment: Good call, unfortunately, no effect. I've updated the code on the demo site, still the same styling issue.

Answer (score -2):

```
<html lang="en" >
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.css">
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
      <script language="javascript">
         angular
            .module('firstApplication', ['ngMaterial'])
            .controller('listController', listController);

         function listController ($scope) {
            var self = this;            
            self.allContacts = loadContacts();
            self.contacts = [self.allContacts[0]];

            function loadContacts() {
               var contacts = [
                  'Roberto Karlos',
                  'Bob Crestor',
                  'Nigel Rick',
                  'Narayana Garner'                  
               ];
               return contacts.map(function (c, index) {
                     var cParts = c.split(' ');
                     var contact = {
                        name: c,
                        email: cParts[0][0].toLowerCase() + '.' + cParts[1].toLowerCase() + '@example.com',
                        image: 'http://lorempixel.com/50/50/people?' + index
                     };
                     contact._lowername = contact.name.toLowerCase();
                     return contact;
               });
            }
         }                 
      </script>      
   </head>
   <body ng-app="firstApplication"> 
      <div id="listContainer" ng-controller="listController as ctrl" layout="column" ng-cloak>
         <md-content>
             <md-list>
               <md-subheader class="md-no-sticky">Contacts</md-subheader>
               <md-list-item class="md-2-line contact-item" ng-repeat="(index, contact) in ctrl.allContacts"
                  ng-if="ctrl.contacts.indexOf(contact) < 0">
                  <img ng-src="{{contact.image}}" class="md-avatar" alt="{{contact.name}}" />
                  <div class="md-list-item-text compact">
                     <h3>{{contact.name}}</h3>
                     <p>{{contact.email}}</p>
                  </div>
                  <md-divider ng-if="!$last"></md-divider>
               </md-list-item>
            </md-list>
            <md-list>
               <md-subheader class="md-no-sticky">Contacts (With Insets)</md-subheader>
               <md-list-item class="md-2-line contact-item" ng-repeat="(index, contact) in ctrl.allContacts"
                  ng-if="ctrl.contacts.indexOf(contact) < 0">
                  <img ng-src="{{contact.image}}" class="md-avatar" alt="{{contact.name}}" />
                  <div class="md-list-item-text compact">
                     <h3>{{contact.name}}</h3>
                     <p>{{contact.email}}</p>
                  </div>
                  <md-divider md-inset ng-if="!$last"></md-divider>
               </md-list-item>
            </md-list>
         </md-content>   
       </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This answer does explain or illuminate the problem. Copy-And-Paste code may solve this particular issue, but it has limited value to other users. Please expand this answer by describing what you think the problem or solution is, and how you propose it should be solved.